# JQuery Not Working on Custom User Control in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a custom user control that has on it a text box, and a couple of compare validator controls. Also I am using JQuery to apply a mask to the text box for a date format. The mask I am using is from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ and I am applying as shown on their website.

When I move the code on to a .Net Page everything works fine. However, when I move the code to an ascx and then apply the control to the page, the mask isn't being applied. I have applied the JQuery to the ascx, and have also tried moving back to the aspx to no avail. It is very simple what I am doing but I can't for the sake of me work out why it is not working.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with ID of the element in the HTML.
Controls in User Controls have the parent namespace attached to the ID's generated for HTML.

Can you post the javascript?

Comment: Yes, in the user control, I applied the following:

Comment: Sorry, hit return by mistake. Anyhow, in the user control

Comment: <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Then, added the as follows:jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
});

Comment: Using date in the jquery could be problem. Once the page is rendered can you look at view source and see what is the id assigned to the textbox?